# JavaScript event delegation - how to prevent parent's event from firing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `ul` list with 3 `li`s inside it. these `li`s are buttons to alter the margin of the `ul` in order to create the effect of a slideshow. `li` buttons are all working fine. but whenever ul is clicked, i.e., any area other than `li` in `ul`, i'm getting a wrong margin for `ul`. wud u help me stop the event from firing on `ul`?

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words.

Comment: Before you try to fix it, learn the right terminology of event bubbling and capturing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/1671639).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, all i want is to prevent the execution of the event that causes the wrong margin to be applied to `ul`. this happens only when i click anywhere outside of `li`. anyway thanks for ur suggeation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**:

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

For example:

```
$('ul').on('click','li',function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: wud u explain the javascript way of doing this?

Comment: You can apply the same way for pure javascript.

Comment: @user3559645, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Comment: @user3559645: This *is* JavaScript. It's using jQuery (a library, not a language), but then, you've tagged `jquery` in your question. If you want an answer using just the DOM, don't tag `jquery` in your question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i wouldn't be wanting to use jquery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowderi don't want to import the library on my website.

Comment: so, if event.stopPropogation is called on ul, lis will still work fine?

Comment: @user3559645: If you don't want to use jQuery, why did you tag the question with jQuery?

Comment: i wanted all those jquery experts to answer this as well...

Comment: and, is bubbles 'true' by default?

Comment: @user3559645: And how are the "jQuery experts" supposed to know that you don't want to use jQuery?

Comment: i wud have given my code. sorry... it's in pure javascript...

Comment: @user3559645: *"i wanted all those jquery experts to answer this as well..."* That's called "tag spamming" and it's not remotely okay on SO.